# Why does xserver require a physical screen?

Tags: x-server, headless, hardware-acceleration

I was searching for a solution to run a graphical application without a physical screen. The application is showing multiple hardware accelerated video streams with gstramer-vaapi.

I dont want to render anything on a physical screen, but still be able to make screen recordings of the app. e. g. via gstreamer ximagesrc

Tried: Xvfb Xdummy Xpra Xrdp xserver-xorg-video-dummy

Nothing really worked out so far.

I am wondering why a normal xserver needs a physical screen at all? Just a software issue or is it really a hardware requirement?

Comment: You're asking the equivalent of "Why do I need a camera to film things?". You just do. The nature of xserver is that it requires drawing things to some sort of screen. The [documentation](https://www.x.org/wiki/FAQErrorMessages/#index5h2) states that one of its requirements is that it be able to iterate the physical screens of a device.

Comment: OK, but still bit unclear where the requirement comes from. In a  dream world I could just pass a config to xerserver,  which says:  Please assume a display with xy resolution and don't care if the monitor cable is plugged in.

Comment: The requirement exists because xserver is "...an implementation of the X Window System...." (see the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server)) which requires a screen. Any well-developed graphical system is going to check regardless of what you tell it.

Comment: Have you tried xpra with `vglrun`?